# Coldfusion Administrator - connect to data source via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, coldfusion

I'd like to configure my coldfusion instance to connect to a MySQL database over SSH but I'm not really sure how.

Basically, I have an EC2 instance in the same region as an RDS instance for the purposes of a development environment. I want to hook into my Production RDS instance so that I can do some tests with production data for a specific feature I'm working on but it's turning out to be quite a bit of trouble since it's in a different region.

I'd rather not alter AWS in any way to achieve this. So far the only thing I could think to try was to SSH into my EC2 instance and setup a tunnel like this

`ssh -i ./mykey.pem -N -L 3306:localhost:3306 username@host_ip`

When I enter this command I don't see any output but I assume it is running, however when I try to access my EC2 instance via the web I see this error: `Timed out trying to establish connection`

Is there something wrong with my setup? I know I have the correct key, credentials, and host but I am a bit confused on the ports. I figured my coldfusion admin panel is looking on port 3306 and my database is served on port 3306 so `3306:localhost:3306` seems correct to me but obviously I am doing something wrong.